# Ignore the max_id item in Twitter API when getting resource

Tags: grails, twitter

I'm developing **Grails app** that getting resource from **Twitter** restful api. 
When I get the resource having many items, it may have many pages. I used parameters **max_id** for getting the next page but the results always included the item that is **max_id** I inputed. 
Could someone tell me the way to ignore the **max_id** item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **page** parameter instead of **max_id**, and set the number of items you want to get in one page through **count** parametter. 
For example, you can get 10 items in page 2:

```
TWITTER_API_URL?count=10&page=2
```

Note: the maximum items you can get in one page is 200